# Multiple bounties on one question at a same time

Tags: discussion, support

Is it possible to activate multiple bounties on one question at same time from multiple users?

Comment: Just tried, no you can't. "Add bounty" will be hidden if there is open bounty.

Comment: @AndrewT. Is it possible to  add new bounty,If the old bounty is closed?

Comment: This link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty. And for your 2nd question, yes you can.

Comment: Multiple bounties could be a cool feature...

Answer (score 1):

Only 1 bounty can be active on 1 question at the same time. The maximum current bounty at any time for 1 question is 500.

Unlimited number of bounties can be set on any 1 question, just there can only be 1 bounty at a time. So for the next bounty to start, the previous bounty has to be completed.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: [An example of an answer that has received several bounties over the course of its life](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/2958086) if you were looking for one :3